# Iterate through all users - firestore

Tags: firebase, loops, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have the following (simplified) setup in firestore

```
    Collection     Document      FIELD     
    [USERID]   -   [STATUS]   -   date_of_birth: timestamp
                                  last _update: timestamp

    [USERID]   -   [STATUS]   -   date_of_birth: timestamp
                                  last _update: timestamp

    [USERID]   -   [STATUS]   -   date_of_birth: timestamp
                                  last _update: timestamp

    [USERID]   -   [STATUS]   -   date_of_birth: timestamp
                                  last _update: timestamp
...
```

I want to build a firebase function where, based on the date of birth, the last_update is not allowed to be older than one year (365 days). If last_update > 365 I want to send the user an notification email.

My problem is, how can I iterate through all the [UDERID]'s? What is the best way to do this?
Is there a way to get all USERID's (more than 4000) in an array and iterate through them or is there another way?

I saw that there should be a way https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#node.js but I have no idea how to implement this within google cloud functions.

Does someone has an idea/solution???

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What have you tried? It seems that you want to iterate over a Firestore collection, not over the users declared in the Auth service.

Comment: To clarify; you are looking to craft a Cloud Function the performs a query and then generate an email based on those results. Is that correct?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec since I don't know how to do the iteration I have tried more or less nothing. I tried to understand the example given by google (see link in questions) but I dont know how to handle it. For you question, yes you are right, I want to iterate through a firestore collection (if that is possible) but sind I use the authentication service from firestore, both ways (firestore collection and Auth Service) would work

Comment: @Jay: Correct! the aim is that in the end, all users who didn't do an update in the last 365 days get a reminder email

Comment: Here's the deal, we are not a code writing service and this site is really about assistance with existing code. Only you know the parameters of your project so make an attempt to write that code and when you get stuck ask about it.

Comment: You will needs two things 1) A [scheduled function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) that tells the cloud query function to run on a regular basis and then 2) A [Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#execute_intensive_tasks_in_the_cloud_instead_of_in_your_app) that performs the query and sends the email. Note that in that section one of the bullet points is *Send bulk email to users* which is exactly what you're asking about. There are examples on their site, videos on youtube and lots of Q&A here about that topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured out that the design of my database is not really optimal but if someone is interrested in the answer, please find the solution below:

This is the indes.js for functions

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
const serviceAccount = require('./cerdentials.json')
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "https://test-data-eda4b.firebaseio.com"
});

const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    // true for 465, false for other ports
    auth: {
        user: 'your email', // generated ethereal user
        pass: 'passowrd', // generated ethereal password
    },
});

const auth = admin.auth();
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.sendEmailToUsers = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 120 minutes').onRun(async (context) => {
    await fatchUsers("").then(res => {
        console.log(res);
    }).catch(e => { console.log(e) })
})

async function fatchUsers (token) {
    if (token != "") {
        return await auth.listUsers(4, token).then(async (usersList) => {
            usersList.users.forEach(user => {
                db.collection(user.uid).doc('status').get().then(async snapshot => {
                    if (snapshot.exists) {
                        if (snapshot.data().notifications_softskills_activated) {
                            console.log("send email to this user : " + user.email);
                            var Email_Res = await sendMail(user.email)
                            functions.logger.info(Email_Res)
                        }
                    }
                })
            })
            if (usersList.pageToken != undefined) {
                await fatchUsers(usersList.pageToken)
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        })
    } else {
        return await auth.listUsers(4).then(async (usersList) => {
            usersList.users.forEach(user => {
                db.collection(user.uid).doc('status').get().then(async snapshot => {
                    if (snapshot.exists) {
                        if (snapshot.data().notifications_softskills_activated) {
                            console.log("send email to this user : " + user.email);
                            var Email_Res = await sendMail(user.email)
                            functions.logger.info(Email_Res)
                        }
                    }
                })
            })
            if (usersList.pageToken != undefined) {
                await fatchUsers(usersList.pageToken)
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        })
    }
}

async function sendMail (email) {
    return await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        const mailOptions = {
            from: "testuser@gmail.com", // sender address
            to: email, // list of receivers
            subject: 'test mail', // Subject line
            html: '<h1>this is a test mail.</h1>'// plain text body
        };
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err, info) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
            else {
                resolve(info);
            }
        })
    })
}
```